# ASP sending duplicate Emails

Tags: asp-classic

I am doing some maintence on an ASP website, and have found that it is sending duplicate emails. I cannot figure out how it is doing this. I have pasted the code here
http://pastebin.com/Beb94PiC

On line 443 is the function SendMsg2. As far as I can tell the function is only called once. Any alerts or messages only come up once.

When the emails are sent the objMessage.TO = email1 comes in once, and then does not appear on any of the second emails. I am thinking that whatever is making it run twice is also clearing the variable.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is named "SendMsg2" but in Line 478 you set

```
SendMsg = objMessage.Send
```

Perhaps that has some side effects when function **SendMsg** exists.

Answer (score 0):

Off hand, I don't see anything glaring that I can simply put a finger on to help. The best way to solve ASP issues is one of two avenues:

1. Encapsulate the logic in a VB COM component
2. Use Response.Write

Personally, VB COM is a lot of overhead for a legacy application. While it allows for better instrumentation, you have to write a lot of code. Unless the application has a much longer shelf life than it should at this time, not your best bet. That leaves #2.

Response.Write entry and exit from each routine. Youc an then see the flow printed out and determine where the mail routine is being called a second time. If that does nothing, then it could be user clicking the button more than once (impatient user). If the latter, you should make a button disable.

One way to tracking things down is add a "session id" to the mix. refactor the mail routine(s) to accept an id value and then you can code "if session ID then don't fire off email" into the mix. The ID gets stored after the first email is sent off and any additional calls will see the id already in the mix. I say session id in quotes, as you both have to work with the concept of session and the concept of initial flow to cover both user error (clicking more than once) and code flow error. If you can send multiple emails in a single session, you need to keep some type of "I sent this email in this session" value in the mix so you don't add the error of not sending emails to the mix.

You should take the time to both correct the flow and correct user error. But take the time to troubleshoot first, so you see if there are any other artifacts. In classic ASP code only, this means writing values to the Response stream (so crude, like hand push lawn mowers?).

Comment: I have done a response.write , in the mail function and it only output once. I am able to reproduce this issue every time without fail, so I know that it is not a case of the button being double clicked. I have even tried to remove the mail function, and put the email code where mail is called, and it is still running twice. This is the website http://www.cpi-ontario.com/memberships/signup.asp

I am going to try and do the session ID, that sounds like it will fix it. But it would be really nice to know why it's running twice..

Comment: Ok so i split the form into two pages, now there is no chance that is running twice. it is still sending 2 emails. So somehow the email function must have an error.

Comment: Or there is an error on server configuration. It may be caught in a retry scenario after a success. Or not clearing already sent messages before they are reprocessed. You have to cover both scenarios. If you only send once per session, or once per session per type of email, it will solve your issue. Always nice to know why, but I find diminishing returns on figuring out why on legacy programming methodologies.